# Does this test value create an infection in the system?

Tags: java, unit-testing, error-handling

I have a test case value of:

```
List<String> string = new LinkedList();
string.add("Hello"); string.add("hi"); string.add("bye");
```

Testing the following method:

```
// Will return longest length of a string within the list. 
public int maxLengthOfString(List<String> listOfStrings) {
    int maxLength - Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int index = 0;
    if (listOfStrings != null) {
        while(index < strings.size()){
            if(strings.get(index).length() > maxLength){
                maxLengthOfString = listOfStrings.get(index).length();
                index++;
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
}
return maxLengthOfString;
```

I thought infection in the R.I.P. model meant that the program was put into an invalid state at some point during the execution. The list above will still skip index 1, but it's not in an invalid state because the purpose of the method is to check the longest String, and index 1 is not the longest.

My professor said that this is an infection because index 1 is skipped.

Is this an infection, in regards to the following webpage: http://www.ironiacorp.com/apps/wiki/testing/RIP_model

Comment: You have a problem with braces in your code

Comment: and with newly invented `!-` operator.

Comment: You only ever look at the first element, even if the list is empty.  Can you provide a link to what you mean by "infection"?

Comment: You can try `listOfStrings.stream().mapToInt(String::length).max()`

Comment: Sorry guys I updated my code.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It looks like he is talking about [this](http://www.ironiacorp.com/apps/wiki/testing/RIP_model)

Comment: It doesn't change the state of the program at all, so it's hard to see how it would count as infection...

Comment: @MiguelJ.In the code you have now, index=1 is not skipped. BTW You can use a plain for loop for the index or a for-each loop for the elements.

Comment: Lol I'm sorry , I updated the code again... It definitely is broken now, I promise. @PeterLawrey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's broken now as it counts on two entries instead of one.  This is where a for-each loop would not only be much shorter, but would also not have an error.

```
        if(strings.get(index).length() > maxLength){
            maxLengthOfString = listOfStrings.get(index).length();
            index++; // skip an entry.
        }
        index++;
```

You could say the the first line `index++;` is the fault however, the system is not guarenteed to be incorrect at this point and a minor change to the code shows that it can be corrected without change it.

```
        if(strings.get(index).length() > maxLength){
            maxLengthOfString = listOfStrings.get(index).length();
            index++; // skip an entry.
        } else
            index++;
```

IMHO there is nothing about the code which suggest that later code couldn't reverse the "damage" caused, thus I don't agree that "after executing the location which has a fault, the state of the program must be incorrect"

You should just write

```
public int maxLengthOfString(List<String> listOfStrings) {
    int maxLength = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    if (listOfStrings != null)
        for(String s : listOfStrings)
            if (maxLength < s.length())
                maxLength = s.length();
     return maxLength;
}
```

Comment: This is a question that was proposed in class. In regards to the definition of Infection in the model referenced above, is this considered an infection?

Comment: @MiguelJ. IMHO  That depends on where you believe the fault is. I don't believe this is a term which is in common use.